# Magento 1.9.4.0 Checkout and cart page broken

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, magento-1.9.4.0

I have upgraded my website from 1.9.1.1 to 1.9.4.0. I am facing the issue of cart and checkout page get broken when the customer is logged in. If we disable the compilation or disable system log, both pages working fine.